# preg_match_all not working in array

Tags: php

I want to display result after searching an array but only title coming as result, but I want to display more values.

1) If I using following code then entire data coming in long string like

```
Array
(
[] => SONY CDX-G1150U - CD, USB, FM/AM Tuner with MP3/WMA Playback (Single DIN)59902 Pre-Out (Rear + Sub Switchable) Digital Clarity Tuner Subwoofer Easy Connection EQ3 stage 2 / Bollywood EQ mode / Illumination - Red 55W x 4 Output Power (Dynamic Reality Amp 2) Steering Remote Input Ready Mega Bass 2 Year Sony India Warranty http://www.snapdeal.com/product/sony-cdxg1150u-cd-usb-fmam/914627741http://n1.sdlcdn.com/imgs/a/o/m/SONY-CDX-G1150U-CD-USB-SDL133242160-1-51ec4.jpg311Car Audio & Video310Automotive4017in stock
)

    $r = $array3['title'];
    $r .= $array3['mrp'];
    $r .= $array3['description'];
    $r .= $array3['link'];
    $r .= $array3['image_link'];
    $r .= $array3['sub_category_id'];
    $r .= $array3['sub_category_name'];
    $r .= $array3['category_id'];
    $r .= $array3['category_name'];
    $r .= $array3['offer_price'];
    $r .= $array3['availability'];

$matches = array();

$pattern = "/\bSony\b/";
if(preg_match($pattern,$r) || preg_match($pattern,$ss) ){
        $matches[$key]=$r;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($matches);
```

---

2) If I using following code (with or condition) then also same result displaying.

```
$r = $array3['title'];
$ss = $array3['mrp'];

$matches = array();

$pattern = "/\bSony\b/";
if(preg_match($pattern,$r) || preg_match($pattern,$ss) ){
        $matches[$key]=$r;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($matches);
```

Comment: you ask in questin in array

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until no code can be removed while still running into the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, try to use something like

```
$matches = array();
foreach($array3 as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
        $matches[] = $array3 
    }
}
print_r($matches)
```

Or by more clear in your question